# Is dropping and recreating an index required to alter a column size that is not included in the index?

Tags: oracle11g

I have a script that drops 3 indexes, alters columns in the same table but unrelated to those indexes, and recreates the indexes.  The indexes are on large tables that take 45min to recreate.  Is it essential to drop and recreate the indexes?

```
DROP INDEX index1;

ALTER TABLE table1 MODIFY colNotInIndex VARCHAR(4000);

CREATE INDEX index1 ON table1(col0, col1, col2)
 TABLESPACE INDX
 STORAGE ( INITIAL 100k NEXT 100k PCTINCREASE 0)
/
```

DB is Oracle 11g

Answer (score 2):

If you are not altering any of the columns in the indexes, there is no need to drop and recreate the indexes.

If you are updating the data in the non-indexed columns-- if you are, for example, updating `colNotInIndex` to store additional data before rebuilding the index-- and those updates cause a large number of rows to get migrated, it is possible that it will be more efficient to do this DML with the indexes disabled (or dropped though dropping the index is riskier and harder to maintain).  Whether the additional index maintenance would add more time to the process than rebuilding the index is something you would have to test but based on your description, it seems unlikely that dropping and recreating the indexes would save time.